# Getting largest reference in sql query with cast

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, max

I have a little sql problem in my vba project that I can't solve. I have a table that besides his ID also has another unique reference. This column is named "Ref_Q" and is Text: "13/45". With 13 from the year were in and another unique number. Now I wan't to get the largest Ref_Q from my table. First I got this:

```
SELECT * FROM Reports WHERE Ref_Q = (SELECT MAX(Ref_Q) FROM Reports);
```

Everything went fine untill I got a Ref_Q larger then 99. So I had "13/102" and he always takes Ref_Q "13/99". So I tried something like this:

```
SELECT CAST(SUBSTRING(MAX(Ref_Q),4) AS Int) FROM Reports
```

But now I keep getting error:

```
Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'CAST(SUBSTRING(MAX(Ref_Q),4) AS Int)'
```

Comment: Don't hard code the value in Substring try to get the value after "/". this should help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query (using SQL Server syntax):

```
SELECT *
FROM Reports
WHERE Ref_Q = (SELECT top 1 Ref_Q
               FROM Reports r
               ORDER BY left(Ref_Q, 2) desc,
                        cast(substring(Ref_Q, 4, len(Ref_Q) - 3) as int) desc
              );
```

This uses `order by` instead of `max()` to fetch the largest value according to your rules.  By the way, you could fix this by zero-padding the numbers, using  `'13\0102'` and `'13\0099'`.

By the way, if you only want want row, you can just use the subquery:

```
               SELECT top 1 *
               FROM Reports r
               ORDER BY left(Ref_Q, 2) desc,
                        cast(substring(Ref_Q, 4, len(Ref_Q) - 3) as int) desc
```

EDIT:

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/52de1/7) is a SQL Fiddle showing them in operation.

Now I see it is labelled access.  Oops.  I think this might work:

```
SELECT *
FROM Reports
WHERE Ref_Q = (SELECT top 1 Ref_Q
               FROM Reports r
               ORDER BY left(Ref_Q, 2) desc,
                        cint(mid(Ref_Q, 4, len(Ref_Q) - 3)) desc
              );
```

(I do note, however, that your original query uses `cast()` which is not in Access as far as I know.)

Comment: When I try the first one, I get a syntax error on the subquery.

Comment: I used your last query (the subquery). SELECT  top 1 *
               FROM Reports r
               ORDER BY left(Ref_Q, 2) desc, mid(Ref_Q, 4) desc and replaced substring with mid. and I still get 13/99 :S

Comment: @Vinny . . . I don't think that will work.  I put the wrong version in the original answer.  If you are using Access, the last might work (or just the subquery).

Comment: the edit works ! thanks a million times ! :D i was breaking my head on this